# Can't get proper result from elasticsearch based on query and document tokenization

Tags: elasticsearch, search, tokenize, n-gram, elasticsearch-analyzers

I'm trying to implement a search system in which I need to use Edge NGRAM Tokenizer. Settings for creating an index are shown below. I have used same tokenizer for both documents and search query.
(Documents are in Perisan language)

```
PUT /test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "autocomplete_search": {
          "tokenizer": "autocomplete"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "autocomplete": {
          "type": "edge-ngram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 10,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**The problem shows up when I get 0 hits (results) from searching term 'آلمانی' in docs while I have a doc with data : 'آلمان خوب است'.**

As you can see the result for analyzing term 'آلمانی' shows that it generates token 'آلمان' and works properly.

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "آ",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "آل",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "آلم",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "آلما",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "آلمان",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "آلمانی",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 6,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

The searching query shown below gets 0 hits.

```
GET /test/_search
{
  "query": {"match": {
    "title": {"query": "آلمانی" , "operator": "and"}
  }}
}
```

However searching term 'آلما' returns doc with data 'آلمان خوب است'.
How can I fix this problem?

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this DevTicks post by Ricardo Heck which solved my problem.
[enter the link for more detailed description](https://devticks.com/how-to-improve-your-full-text-search-in-elasticsearch-with-ngram-tokenizer-e346f29f8ddb)

I changed my mapping setting like this:

```
    "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "autocomplete_search",
          "fields": {
            "ngram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "autocomplete"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And now I get doc "آلمان خوب است" by searching the term "آلمانی".